# K-Means Algorithm - Feature Selection

Tags: feature-selection, k-means

Suppose I've this dataset:

```
Employee_ID  Store_ID  Company_ID  Stock_ID  Product_Value
    1            1          1          2           3.7
    4            1          4          2            8
                           ...
```

Where:

```
Employee_ID: Is the unique number for a employee that sold the product
Store_ID: Unique number for Store Chain
Company_ID: Unique number for product supplier
Stock_ID: Unique number for the product purchased
Product_Value: Product Value
```

And I want to make a segmentation over my dataset using K-Means... Its make sense use all the variables for my dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you want to use those variables to define closeness then yes, you just have to encode them differently. You should use a one-hot-encoding for the discrete variables (e.g., Employee_ID, Store_ID, etc.) and just the Product_Value as is. I answered a similar question about K-means for just categorical variables (like Employee_ID) so I've copied the code below that gives a quick demo for using the Clusters as a feature for predicting something after you use K-means. As I said in my old answer, in general, this framework isn't optimal but it's okay for a simulation.

```
library(glmnet)
library(Matrix)
n <- 1e5
nclusters <- 5
set.seed(420)
ls <- data.frame(sample(letters, n, replace=TRUE))
xs <- sparse.model.matrix(~.,data=ls)
print(head(xs))  
# Now let's run k-means
out <- kmeans(xs, centers=nclusters)
bs <- rep(1, dim(xs)[2])
# Let's run k-means on the different categories
clusterpred <- data.frame(out[[1]])
ys <- xs %*% bs + rnorm(n)
print(table(clusterpred))
# Now let's use a clustered data set to predict some outcome
cxs <- sparse.model.matrix(~.,data=clusterpred)
model <- glmnet(y=ys, x=xs, alpha=0)
cmodel <- glmnet(y=ys, x=cxs, alpha=0)

# Predictions
yhat <- predict(model, xs)
yhatc <- predict(cmodel, cxs)
# Looking at the difference RMSEs 
print(sqrt( sum( (ys-yhat)**2 )))
print(sqrt( sum( (ys-yhatc)**2 )))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Never apply k-means to `id` columns

Even when they are numerical: the *mean* does not make sense.

Instead, you need to **aggregate** and pivot your data appropriately. One row per entity that you want to cluster (e.g. stores, or employees?). Multiple `value` columns. No `id` except the row number.

Don't forget to normalize / preprocess your data. E.g. one store may have a much better location. If you cluster your employees, expect to find a cluster that is simply a store. (Which is a correct, albeit useless, clustering).